# Authentication problem with google cloud function gen2 in golang on firebase routing

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Im testing go gen2 google cloud functions, the code of the function was deployed ok, it works ok, everything is fine. The function is named  readrequest, and it is open to everybody. You can reach it https://readrequest-v7disnxdea-uc.a.run.app

I also add mapping to a dedicated subdomain without problem.

Now I'm trying to route in one web firebase app. For that I've added a route to firebase.json

the rules in firebase.json looks like:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "rewrites": [

      {
        "source": "/l",
        "function": "l3"
      },
      {
        "source": "/gotest",
        "function": "readrequest"
      },
      {
        "source": "/gotest/**",
        "function": "readrequest"
      },
      {
        "source": "/rc1",
        "function": "rc1"
      },
      {
        "source": "/rc2",
        "function": "rc2"
      },
      {
        "source": "/rc2/**",
        "function": "rc2"
      },
      {
        "source": "/rc1/**",
        "function": "rc1"
      }
    ],
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
}
```

I can reach the funcion, always ask for authentication, but it doesn't work even if I accept to authenticate. I've created the function in us-central1 to avoid problems.

The error is:

```
Error: Forbidden
Your client does not have permission to get URL /readrequest/gotest/asdf from this server.
```

If I misspell the function name I get the same error, so it is like the router isn't locating the function, but don't why not.

Comment: Cloud Functions gen2 is based on Cloud Run. I know nothing to Firebase but try to apply the Cloud Run requirement to your Cloud Functions gen2, and it should work

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I'm not sure what do you mean. The function works well if I call directly to the cloudrun instance. I suppose that the problem is in the firebase side, perhaps gen2 is not supported.

Comment: Maybe, but I also know that Cloud Run and Firebase integration exists. That's why, I recommend to follow this integration instead of the usual Cloud Functions integration because Cloud Functions gen2 is simply a wrapper of Cloud Run

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere got it. Thanks, that is the solution, if you replace "function":  "readrequest" by         "run": {
          "serviceId": "readrequest", 
          "region": "us-central1"     
        } It works like a charm! If you write it as solution I will give  to you  the answer.

Comment: Thank you for confirming. I added an answer based on your comment. I could helps others in the same situation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Cloud Functions gen2 runs on top of Cloud Run (url, permission, logs, and many other things are the same!), the way to reach Cloud Functions gen2 is not the usual Cloud Functions gen1 manner, it's the Cloud Run one!

Buy the way, replace the function (gen1) reference `"function": "readrequest"`, the functions (gen2, i.e. Cloud Run) reference `"run": { "serviceId": "readrequest", "region": "us-central1" }`